# How can I find the area of a non-right triangle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I know the equation is $\frac {bh * sin(c)}{2}$, but I only have the top angle, which is 42 degrees, and the base, which is 60 ft. So far, I tried using the equation, but there is no h variable, so I have no idea on how to solve it. Is it even possible? If so, I don't need the answer, but at least the formula to solve it

Comment: The area of any triangle is height times base divided by $2$. What is that $\sin(c)$ factor you have?

Comment: If you know the lengths of all sides, you can also use Heron’s Formula.

Comment: If it's an isosceles triangle, you can bisect the "top" angle and create two right-angled triangles.

Comment: **Knowing just the top angle and the length of the base is *not* enough information to find the area of the triangle.** Imagine dragging and tilting the top vertex, which would increase the height of the triangle, while keeping the top angle and the length of the base the same. This means you can make many triangles with the same top angle and length of base, but with different areas.

Comment: You need to know at least $3$ information; two sides and an angle, three sides, two angles and a side, or such kind of information. I think you are given that the triangle is isosceles.

Comment: Here is [**an example of two different triangles with the same base and same opposite angle**](https://i.imgur.com/kNDniaA.png) (angles $a$ and $b$ in the picture are the same), but different areas (because they have different heights, shown in blue)